# Issue with NumberPicker images showing up offset

Tags: android, android-layout

I used the example code from http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5 and compiled the example and it displayed fine.  When I copied the code into my application the graphic of the increment and decrement buttons show up offset to the right.  Any ideas what I did wrong?

I also tried using his revised code from http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=32 and got the same results.

Comment: show us your code , i'm pretty sure that you would have the answer immediately if you put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something really weird with n-patch images. IIRC you need individual drawables for each density. Maybe you can get by with just drawable-hdpi versions.

See my "patch" for this against ADW Launcher
https://github.com/teslacoil/adw_launcher/commit/32cf073725d129149c903cb7b924279336b4bff3

Comment: That was exactly the issue.  Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [my number picker](https://github.com/Knickedi/android-toolbox/tree/master/number_picker). (I struggled with the very same issue.)
It's a port from original number picker source, enhanced for public use (custom attributes + view or preference which will persist an integer) and it also includes `hdpi` resources (which are compressed to minimum required size).

There's also a great feature (at least I think so):
You can use it in a horizontal way by specifying `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

[image]